# PA Flow to get attachments from each folder and place into SP list

Tags: sharepoint, automation, onedrive, power-automate

I am trying to create a Power Automate flow that will allow me to hit a button and take files contained in each folder within a directory and place them in their own unique list item. The purpose is to list job candidate info within a list taken from a form from a third party software. Each form filled out creates a folder with the name of each candidate containing their documents in OneDrive. This flow is creating the unique list row while also attempting to add the attachments which makes it a bit trickier.

I've already built a flow that I thought worked but the attachments do not have any content and will not load. Below is the flow I built

[Flow part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaCKH.jpg)

[Flow part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzJBe.jpg)

Still figuring out how to best go about populating the attachments field within each row but playing around with using copy files and some sort of loop but haven't had much success. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To better help you with your question, can you describe it in more detail?I can't reproduce your problem.